# Dimension of a subspace of $2\times2$ Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations

The question is asking to find the dimension of the subspace $W$, where, $V = M_{2,2}$,
$$
W = \{A \in V: AB= BA\}
$$
where
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\\\end{bmatrix}$$
I defined an arbitrary matrix $A$ which contains the entries $a,b,c,d$. Then I considered the equailty and multiplied the matrices in both sides then got:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a+3b&2a+4b\\c+3d&2c+4d\\\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a+2c&b+2d\\3a+4c&3b+4d\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Then I set:

1)$a+3b = a+2c$

2) $2a+4b = b+2d$

3) $c+3d = 3a+4c$

4) $2c+4d = 3b+4d$

The problem is that things got complicated to find $a,b,c$ and $d$, which allow us to find the dimension! What is the next step?

Comment: Next step: solve these four homogeneous linear equations in four variables for their general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equations give
\begin{align*}
3b&=2c\\
a+c&=d\\
\end{align*}

Meaning that once $a$ and $c$ are known you can deduce $b$ an $d$.

Consequently the matrix $A$ has the following form
\begin{pmatrix} 
a & 2c/3 \\
c & a+c 
\end{pmatrix}

Can you conclude from there ?

Comment: What do you mean by finding a and c? as numbers or variables?

Comment: @DoctorMath see my edit, you can express $A$ with only $a$ and $c$ that is what I meant

Comment: so we have 2 free variables?

Comment: yes @DoctorMath

Comment: Thank you man!!